# Using React Palette and set state

Tags: reactjs

I am using `react-palette` to extract vibrant colors. I have this in the render method:

```
          <Palette image={this.state.img.src}>
                {palette => {
                    this.setState({vibrantColors:palette.vibrant});
                    console.log(palette);
                    return(
                    <div>
                        Text with the vibrant color
                    </div>
                )}}
            </Palette>
```

What I want is to set state with these colors, but in above example, I am getting this error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I know why is this error and that it is bad practice to set state inside render method, but I don't know how to use that library and set state with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be doing a setState from inside a render which will trigger a render which will setState again etc...

I. So one way to go about it is to move `<Palette>` tag higher up. This is typically useful if you want to continue using the palette to render something with it.

```js
<Palette image={this.state.img.src}>
  {palette => {
    // no need to seState, we can just use it here or pass it to handlers
    // you know... the react way
    return <div>Text with the vibrant color</div>;
  }}
</Palette>
```

II. Now, the other way of doing it, if you **really** must store the palette in the state or sth (maybe you have your reasons) is to look at how react-palette has been coded and use the underlying magical call that gives us the palette:

1. Looking at [Palette.js](https://github.com/leonardokl/react-palette/blob/9a44890038e406cdec12261db64a503aadd3e893/src/Palette.js#L12) we see usage of an internal util function called `getImagePalette`
2. Next, looking at [getImagePalette](https://github.com/leonardokl/react-palette/blob/9a44890038e406cdec12261db64a503aadd3e893/src/utils/getImagePalette.js#L5) we see that it's actually just a wrapper to an npm package [node-vibrant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-vibrant)
3. From node-vibrant's [documentation](https://github.com/akfish/node-vibrant#nodejs--browserify) we see that we can just use the following (instead of react-palette)

```sh
# install the version ^3.0.0
yarn add "node-vibrant@^3.0.0"
# or npm install --save "node-vibrant@^3.0.0"
```

```js
import * as Vibrant from 'node-vibrant';
//...

doStuffWithPalette = (imgSrc) => {
  Vibrant.from(imgSrc).getPalette()
    .then(palette => {
      // do what ever you want with palette, even setState if you want to, just avoid calling it from a render/componentWillUpdate/componentDidUpdate to avoid having the same error you've got in the first place
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // handle errors
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am getting `worker.js Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object` with exact same code as your (third solution).

Comment: @gdfgdfg I changed the import statement on it maybe this will solve it

Comment: I am using and their documentation. Your previous example and their documentation - same result.

Comment: How to make your second example ?

Comment: somehow installing node-vibrant via npm/yarn installs the alpha version which contains this issue. Installing version "^3.0.0" instead, would work perfectly

Comment: @gdfgdfg I updated the answer to take into account the correct installation of the dependency

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :) .